# How to make a button half the width of a UITableViewCell using constraints (Storyboard or Programatically)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I have a project I'm working on that needs two buttons with some data that will take up exactly half the width of the UITableViewCell that they are in.

In the past when I have wanted to do this I usually set a constraint that the button will be equal widths to its superview and give it a multiplier of 0.5.

For some reason however inside the UITableViewCell I can't get the Storyboards to give me this option. The "Equal Widths" constraint in the GUI is grayed out.

[image: Example of what I'm trying to achieve]

I resolved to just do it programmatically so in the custom cell I tied the following code. I've tried putting the `cellInit()` method below being called in the awakeFromNib and that gave an error. I've tried also just calling it on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when the cell is loaded, and got the same error.

import UIKit

class PollCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var option1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var option2: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    //cellInit() //Commented out because causes error
}

func cellInit(){
    option1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: option1, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0))
}
```

}

This is the error that I am getting:

*'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.*

What I'm trying to achieve is pretty standard, so I assume this isn't anything to crazy and I'm probably doing something the wrong way. Either way I assume plenty of newcomers like myself will run into this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition to the answer below would also suggest to make a `UITableViewCell` subclass that sets up the constraints and buttons you'll need. It may help out in the end if you look to further customize that cell.

Comment: I think you should take a few steps back and try to think in smaller steps. You should break this problem down in steps before rushing to assuming you need constraints.  First, you need to implement a custom cell class. Then you need to register this cell in your tableview and instantiate it in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Then you should try to create one button. After that, you should work on the frame of this button to try to move it around. Hint. The cell has a frame called contentView. which you can dynamically link to the button. button1 width =(cell.contentView.frame.width/2 - 0)

Comment: Sorry for not including the code, but the above is an extract FROM my subclass of UITableViewCell, I have the UITableViewDelegate and DataSource setup in my subclass of UITableViewController, and the cell is being instantiated and registered there, so all that was previously done. As for using the frame and using getting the contentView's width, I thought about using that. Is it the apple way to just use frames? I'm fine with doing that, but wanted to learn AutoLayout and constraints better, perhaps I was misinformed and constraints should be avoided.

Comment: @ericgu, For fun I implemented it both ways, with the frame and with constraints. One note on your answer, the contentView.frame.width gives a  width of size 0, so I had to use the UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width instead. I do like using the frame manually because then I have total control over what happens, but I'm still wondering which is the "right" way if there is one to do this.

Comment: My apologies. I was writing pseudo code for you in haste. You should use contentView.frame.maxX / 2 to the get the midPoint of the contentView on the X Axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, we discussed that you leverage `contentView.frame.maxX`

Alternatively, you can use AutoLayout: Make sure you `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`

Assign tags (optional). You only havetwo buttons but for more than two, I would use tags so you don't need to manually type `UIButton` for every button.

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.viewWithTag(1) as UIButton, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 0.33, constant: 0))
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.viewWithTag(2) as UIButton, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 0.66, constant: 0))
```

OR VFL using a Dictionary:

```
for button in buttonsDictionary.keys {
          self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[\(button1)]-[\(button2)]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: buttonsDictionary))
        }
```

call `cell.updateConstraints()` in your cellForRowAtIndexPath in TableView.

You can learn more in the link below: They have an example of two side by side buttons:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1

Comment: For some reason the maxX also gives back a size of 0, for some reason

Comment: Could there be something off with the registering of this CustomCell you subclassed? I had a very similar problem today and this line for me works: label.frame = CGRectMake((contentView.frame.width - profileImageView.frame.maxX)/3, contentView.frame.height/2, 50, 50)

Comment: It could be that I'm using the cell from the storyboard with an id in there rather than in a Xib file with registerClass

Comment: I am not using IB or XiB

Comment: Good luck. You seem to have made progress in a small amount of time

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem like yours before. What I did was put a UIView in the cell first with its top, left, right, bottom constraints set to all 0, then place the button on top of the view. This way I get the 'equal width' option.

Comment: Great Idea, does anyone know why this option is unavailable via UITableViewCell?

Comment: Just put in code what he said here. When doing this make sure you add the constraints like he said of left, top, right, bottom to 0 or the view will be the wrong size and the width constraints won't help. It does work, though I'm frustrated that I have add a view just to access the equal widths constraint